# How do I select a table to inner join based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an SQL select where the query can select a table to inner join based on the value of a main table column. Something like this:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, b.col1
from tblA a
if a.col2 = 'Moe' inner join tblB1 b on tblA.id = tblB1.id
elseif a.col2 = 'Larry' inner join tblB2 b on tblA.id = tblB2.id
elseif a.col2 = 'Curly' inner join tblB3 b on tblA.id = tblB3.id 
else inner join tblB4 b on tblA.id = tblB4.id
```

If a.col2 is any of 'Moe', 'Larry' or 'Curly' the inner join points to their respective table. If not any of the three, the inner join points to a fallback table

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Use `left join`, like this:

```
select a.col1, a.col2,
      coalesce(bm.col1, bl.col1, bc.col1, b.col1) as col1
from tblA a left join
     tblB1 bm
     on a.id = bm.id and a.col2 = 'Moe' left join 
     tblB2 bl
     on a.id = bl.id and a.col2 = 'Larry' left join
     tblB3 bc
     ona.id = mc.id and a.col2 = 'Curly' left join 
     tblB4 b
     on a.id = b.id and
        a.col2 not in ('Moe', 'Larry', 'Curly');
```

If you are using the joins to filter rows as well (that is, expecting that some rows in `a` will not match), then add:

```
where bm.id is not null or bl.id is not null or
      bc.id is not null or b.id is not null
```

This will assure at least one match.

Answer (score 1):

Coytainly!  Give this a try:

```sql
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, COALESCE(b.col1, c.col1, d.col1, e.col1) AS col1
FROM tblA a
LEFT JOIN tblB1 b on a.id = b.id AND a.col2 = 'Moe'
LEFT JOIN tblB2 c on a.id = c.id AND a.col2 = 'Larry'
LEFT JOIN tblB3 d on a.id = d.id AND a.col2 = 'Curly'
LEFT JOIN tblB4 e on a.id = e.id AND a.col2
;
```

This will get the rows from all four "B" tables and only return the appropriate matched one via the `COALESCE` construct.  This assumes `id` is the `PK` in each of the tables.

I was going to include a `NOT IN` in the last `LEFT JOIN` but it's not needed since the `COALESCE` will give priority to the values from the earlier joins.  Nyuk, nyuk, nyuk.

Also, as Gordon suggested, since you have all `inner joins` in your initial query, you'd need to add `WHERE b.id is NOT NULL OR c.id IS NOT NULL OR d.id IS NOT NULL OR e.id IS NOT NULL` to mimic the same behavior (i.e. don't return unmatched rows).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Prepared Statements`

You prepared a String with the query and execute it.

[Check the doc here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)